# docker-compose on cloudbuild / networking issues

Tags: networking, docker-compose, google-cloud-build

Having the wollowing docker-compose file :

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD:'xyz'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
  redis:
    image: 'redis:5-alpine'
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'
  specs:
    image: gcr.io/project_id/container_name:latest
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
      - 'redis'
    build: .
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        ...stuff that require database processing...
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=test
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:@postgres:5432/test_db
    links:
      - postgres
      - redis
volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: cloudbuild
```

and the following cloudbuild step (we're using the [community cloud builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/docker-compose)) :

```
...
- name: 'gcr.io/app-dmx-sh/docker-compose'
    args:
      - 'run'
      - 'specs'
    id: 'specs'
...
```

we keep hitting the following error :

`could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known`

We've also tried to add the `network_mode: cloudbuild` for each containers in the compose file, no success.

What should be done to be able have the compose file network work as expected within this cloudbuild environment ?

Comment: Since it is not recognising the hostname, try using the IP instead

Comment: isn't there a better way to troubleshoot such case ? It feels weird to have broken things within cloudbuild

Comment: Seem that the workaround for that issue currently is to use the IP. However, it would be helpful for the community if you could confirm if the workaround works in your case.
Also post the steps for creating the database for providing with more information